# Report query based on year from dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm facing difficulties in generating a report based on **YEAR** from the **DATE**. The table consists of `date of birth (dob)` which is stored as `YYYY-MM-DD` - Eg. `1955-01-11`. Before generating report, the user has to select the **AGE** and/or **GENDER**. The **AGE** is categorised as:

> 0-17, 18-24, 25-54, 55-64 and 65+

Once the user has selected the **AGE**, the value is captured from the select, say the **AGE** selected was **18-24**. That means `starting age is 18` and `ending age is 24`. So the report to be generated should be of members **between the age of 18 and 24 only**.

My Form:

```
<label name="age">AGE</label>
<select id="age" name="age" class="form-control">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="0-17">0 - 17</option>
    <option value="18-24">18 - 24</option>
    <option value="25-54">25 - 54</option>
    <option value="55-64">55 - 64</option>
    <option value="65-150">65+</option>
</select>
```

My Controller:

```
if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');

    $this->data['results'] = $this->member_model->getMembers($age, $gender);
}
$this->template->build('reports/index', $this->data);
```

My Model:

```
public function getMembers($age="", $gender="") {
      if ($age != "") {
        // separate age (start, end)
        $age = explode('-', $age);

        return $this->db->from($this->table_members)
                          ->select(array(
                            'transmember.firstname',
                            'transmember.lastname',
                            'transmember.dob',
                            'transmember.gender',
                            ))
                          ->where('EXTRACT(YEAR from transmember.dob) >=', $age[1])
                          ->where('EXTRACT(YEAR from transmember.dob) <=', $age[0])
                          ->like('transmember.gender', $gender)
                          ->get()->result();
      }
}
```

The framework used is `CodeIgniter`. Problem faced are:

1. How do I filter data based on only **YEAR**?
2. How do I better structure my queries to allow multiple filter options? eg. By Age, gender, nationality etc. I have tried using `like` to reduce conditional statements.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query in your model.

```
public function getMembers($age="", $gender="") 
     {
        if ($age != "") 
       {
        // separate age (start, end)
          $age = explode('-', $age);
          $this->db->select("firstname,lastname,dob,gender");
          $this->db->from("your_table_name");
          $this->db->where("dob >=",$age[1]);
          $this->db->where("dob <=",$age[0]);
          $this->db->where("gender",$gender);

          $query = $this->db->get();

          if($query->num_rows() > 0)
          {
             return $query->result();
          }
         else
         {
            return NULL;
         }
      }  
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @raham, If you go through my explanation above, I have mentioned **better structure my queries to allow multiple filter options**. I tried using **where** but if nothing is passed **where returns errors**, hence, I've used **like** instead. I'm also joining several tables and querying them as well.